# Call php echo from jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script in my header that calls a php file.

The php file contains data pulled from a remote xspf file, and the output presented in jQuery for refresh purpose. i have 2 echo rules, one for title and one for listeners. right now jQuery calls the file itself which makes the output appear together on a single line.
how can i make jQuery present these echoes separately so i can control their design (CSS)?

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://mysitehere:8000/live.xspf"); 

foreach ($xml->trackList->track as $data) { 
    $radio = $data->location;
    $song  = $data->title;  
    $info = $data->listeners;   
}
echo $song;
echo $info;
?>
```

jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Carga al comienzo
    jQuery('#salida').load('reader.php');   
    setInterval(function() {        
        jQuery('#salida').load('reader.php');   
    }, 2000);
})
</script>

<div id=salida> </div>
```

Comment: Encode your data as JSON, retrieve it with jQuery and process it accordingly (create elements, etc). Right now you are simply taking the response and simply dump it on the page. If you structure the response, you will be able to process it properly with JavaScript.

Comment: can you kindly direct me to a good JSON tutorial to achieve this? im not familiar with JSON..

Comment: Just search for it here on SO or the web. There are many, many resources. That said, using JSON is not the only way of course how you could solve this problem, but in the long you will be more flexible. It also depends on what kind of data you have though.

Comment: Thanx Felix,i will def' follow your advice and learn JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the echoed info into separate elements

```
echo '<div class="Song">'.$song.'</div>';
echo '<div class="Info">'.$info.'</div>';
```

then setup classes in your css for Song, Info (or whatever names you want to give them)